# Convert Named Query to Native Query

Tags: java, sql, named-query, nativequery

I have 2 separate tables mapped to SharedThing and TeamMember.

I have the following named query;

```
SELECT sharedThing 
FROM SharedThing sharedThing,
     TeamMember teamMember 
WHERE teamMember.sharedId = sharedThing.sharedId 
  AND teamMember.userId = :userId
```

So I am passing userId as a parameter.

How do I convert the same to native sql query ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Replace the placeholder with the real value and thats it.

Comment: I wanted to know about the WHERE clause specifically

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `shared_thing` table is mapped to `SharedThing` entity, and `team_member` is mapped to `TeamMember`:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM shared_thing st
JOIN team_member tm on tm.shared_id = st.id and tm.user_id = ?1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` syntax and `*` to select all columns of a table

```
select s.*
from SharedThing s
inner join TeamMember t on t.sharedId = s.sharedId 
where t.userId = 123
```